# how can i apply radius to image with flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, cornerradius

i want to display gridview contains card contains image.
i apply radius to card but it did not apply to its child image

here's my code:

```
child: new GridView.builder(
    itemCount: 20,
    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
      return new Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
        ),
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: new Image.network('http://i.pravatar.cc/1000'),              
        );

    }
  ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default clip behavior for `Card` is `Clip.none`. Set it to e.g. `Clip.antiAlias`:

```dart
Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  child: ...,
)
```